# Casting NaN value

Tags: java, floating-point, nan

I simply learned that `NaN` is `unordered` and I was just playing with `Float` and `Double NaN` and I tried following snippet:

```
System.out.println("Comparing with isNaN method: " + Float.isNaN((float)Double.NaN));
```

I got a question if NaN is Not-a-Number then why casting of NaN is allowed. I want to know what happen at `Architectural Level` when I `cast NaN value`.

Answer (score 2):

In the javadoc you can see that Double.NaN is a Constant of the type Double, so you can cast! Double.Nan is a valid number. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 1):

When you cast, NaN of one type is mapped to NaN of the other type. This is done by the CPU so what you see in Java is what happens at the "Architectural Level"